# Possible to use Push notifications without developer account?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

Is it possible to use push notification without developer account just for testing!

Answer (score 4):

No as of writing this answer we can't do that

As stated here https://www.raywenderlich.com/8164-push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started

We require these for Testing Push Notification:

- An Apple Developer Program membership: To send push notifications, you need a push notification certificate for your App ID, which requires a program membership.
- Push Notifications: You’ll use this utility app to send notifications to a test device

You can use any of the available utility app for the last point.